# How to read table data from PostgreSQL using JDBC in Azure Databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I'm trying to read a postgreSQL table available in the Azure cloud subscription using pyspark, but getting the below error. I'm aware that when we use load function, we should include the format as well. But since this PostgreSQL instance is available in the different azure subscription, i dont have access to PostgreSQL database at all, if that is the case how to infer the schema? or is there any better way to read the data from databricks.

```
df = spark.read.option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://{hostname}:5432&user={username}&password={xxxxx}&sslmode=require").option("dbtable", {tablename}).load()
```

Error:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1169.load.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSource.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSource.scala:211)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:203)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the code implicitly assumes that the format is `parquet`. No matter of the options defined, they're simply ignored by the format.

In other words, the structured query does not use load data using JDBC at all.

That's this part of the error that says so (pretty much):

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;

If you want to read from a JDBC data source, you should include `format("jdbc")` in the query:

```
spark.read.format("jdbc")
```

Comment: Hello @jacekLaskowski, many thanks for the response, when i try to use  spark.read.format("jdbc") stuck with the error message:  **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry**

Comment: Well, that's another issue then. Please read [JDBC To Other Databases](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) in the official docs.